# How to configure Azure to use domain name instead of *.azurewebsites.com?

Tags: php, azure, web-config, asp.net-routing, azure-web-app-service

When I go to my domain, it redirects to my Azure subdomain (x.azurewebsites.com).  How can I fix this so that my domain doesn't redirect?
My config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="MyRule">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" /> 
                    <conditions> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule> 
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Azure manager (manage.windowsazure.com) select your site, then select configure.

Make sure that you have set your domain there.

Answer (score 0):

[Have you tried looking at the documentation?](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/) If you're having a specific issue with any step, let us know, but at least try to put some effort into it.